# Vertically Centering CSS Heading with Floated Controls

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I keep running into cases where I want to have to inline-block elements on opposite ends of the same "line" but I also want them to vertically align.

An example of what I am talking about is here: http://jsfiddle.net/96DJv/4/ (look at the buttons, I want them to align with the heading)

The markup:

```
<div class="people">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="controls">
            <button>Delete</button>
            <select>
                <option>Some Option</option>
            </select>
            <!-- additional inline-block elements -->
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>        
    </div>
    <table class="list">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td><td>14</td><td>200</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jack</td><td>23</td><td>2100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The style:

```
.people {
    width: 400px;
}

.list {
    width: 100%;
}

.list th {
    text-align: left;
}

.title {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.controls {
    float: right;    
}

.head {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

From what I hear floating an element removes your ability to change the vertical align of that element. 
So are the only options I am left with using position: absolute or tables? Is there another way to accomplish this goal?

I've been searching for hours and still haven't found a solution that works.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm seeing a blank fiddle. Anyway, back to the question - it is, I think, not possible to vertically center a floated element with `vertical-align: middle`. However, it is possible using absolute positioning and offsets.

Comment: Fixed the JS Fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Walt,

I came up with one solution making minimal changes to the HTML and modifying the CSS.

HTML

```
<div class="people">
<div class="head">
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1> <-- Moved the H1 tag above the controls div
    <div class="controls">
        <button>Delete</button>
        <select>
            <option>Some Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>                  
</div>
<table class="list">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td><td>14</td><td>200</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jack</td><td>23</td><td>2100</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
 .title {   
      display: table-cell;
    }

.controls {
  display: table-cell;    
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

.head {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8xLtM/

**UPDATE 1:**
Perhaps a better answer if you'd prefer to avoid the display: table markup:

To center the controls, its line-height needs to equal the title's font size + line height.

```
.title {
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.controls {
    float: right; 
    line-height: 4em;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it forces you to use inline elements in the controls div. I should have included that in my example. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on your `head` class and use `align-items: center` to center its content vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/96DJv/5/